# How can I only enter one input in a multiple inputs form to retrieve data?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, forms, visual-studio-2012

I am having a problem with retrieving data using form fields in Visual Studio 2012.

The following code is the form I create:

```
<form>
            <div class="searchForm">
            <p class="insideFormTitle">Symbol:</p>
            <input class="insideFormInput" type="text" name="symbol" autofocus/>
            <p class="insideFormTitle">First Name:</p>
            <input class="insideFormInput" type="text" name="firstName"/>
            <p class="insideFormTitle">Surname:</p>
            <input class="insideFormInput" type="text" name="surname"/>
                <br /><input type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size:26px;">
            </div>
        </form>
```

But when i use Configure Data Source wizard to create a "Where" statement,  the statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE (([Symbol] = ?) AND ([First Name] = ?) AND ([surname] = ?))
```

which means I need to input all three parameters in order to retrieve the data. If i only enter input, for example, "Symbol", nothing will come out.

I am only a newcomer for web development and really have no idea how to search the answer on the internet.

Anyway, thank you for any answer given!

Comment: I've not used Visual Studio in a long time but can you not edit the query after it is built? Surely it allows you to edit it. Because the above query is what you want just need to delete the two AND parts

Comment: The statement has two AND when I create it. And do u mean i should write something like this? "SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE (([Symbol] = ?)  ([First Name] = ?)  ([Surname] = ?))" Do i need to add something in the middle?

Comment: All you want is to retrieve symbol so all you need is SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE (([Symbol] = ?)

Comment: But retrieve symbol is only an example, I also want to retrieve first name without entering symbol and surname and want to retrieve surname without entering symbol and first name

Comment: I see. Well you've 2 options then, either use SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] so that all values are retrieved no matter what value is input, guessing you don't want to do that. Or your going to have to implement some logic, i.e if/else statement so that if only symbol value is entered then do SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE (([Symbol] = ?) and then similarly for the other alternatives i.e if only firstname is input

Comment: when you click add in the where clause, wizard automatically add "and" between conditions. You just have to replace "and" by "or" and it should be ok

Comment: I will think about the second solution but it is too many options when I want to only input two fields because the actually form has 10 more input fields

Comment: Hi Scraaappy, i did try to replace by OR, but what happens is that you still need to input all three fields and the data retrieved are those which meet one of three conditions but all three conditions

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of web development! :)

I'm not terribly familiar with the VS Data Source Wizard but what I've seen done in some code that uses parameterized queries with some optional parameters is to also compare the parameter to an empty string so it doesn't filter if the user didn't enter anything.

```
SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE (([Symbol] = ? OR '' = ?) AND ([First Name] = ? OR '' = ?) AND ([surname] = ? OR '' = ?))
```

You'll have to pass each input from the user twice into the query but I believe this is the logic you are looking for (i.e. you want to display records that match ALL of the inputs the user entered).